# How to fix system hang while rebooting and powering off on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: shutdown, 19.10, reboot

I have some issues with powering off and rebooting on Ubuntu 19.10. The system just hangs about a minute or so when it reaches "target Reboot" and "target power off". Is there a way to fix these issues. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you. 
Here is the PC specification:

```
COMPUTER:
Processor       : AMD A8-7410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics
Memory      : 7024MB (1171MB used)
Machine Type        : Notebook
Operating System        : Ubuntu 19.10
User Name       : anderson (Anderson)
Date/Time       : Sun 19 Apr 2020 10:03:53 AM PST
-Display-
Resolution      : 1366x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : (Unknown)
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation


OPERATING SYSTEM:
Kernel      : Linux 5.3.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 17:37:05 UTC 2020
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.30-0ubuntu2.1) 2.30
Distribution        : Ubuntu 19.10
```

Comment: This delay can be for a number of reasons. As soon as you reboot/shutdown, hit the ESC key and watch the shutdown log. Look at the last line or two to help determine what it's waiting for.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I fixed the problem by switching to lunux mint 19.3. It's running perfectly.